# Select ___where __LIKE ___

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, sql-like

I want to select all the tables which don't contain the character `_` from a database, for this I used the request :

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema="DB_NAME"
AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%_%';
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underscore (`_`) is a single character wildcard in SQL's `LIKE` operator. If you want to treat it as a regular charater, you'll have to explicitly `escape` it:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE  table_schema='DB_NAME' and TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%\_%' ESCAPE `\`;
```

Comment: Thank you, it finally works but without the ' ESCAPE '\' :
`SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE  table_schema="DB_NAME" and TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE "%\_%" `

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

```
TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%\_%'
```

### Long answer

The characters `%` and `_` are both special in `LIKE` expressions.

[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

- `%` Match zero or more characters.
- `_` Mach exactly one character.

If You want to use it in Your query, You have to use escape character. The default is `\`.

- `\%` Mach '%' character.
- `\_` Mach '_' character.

In Your situation it would be:

```
TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%\_%'
```

It is possible to define different escape character, for example `|`.

```
TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%|_%' ESCAPE '|'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way using `REGEXP` in mysql to select every tables that not contains an `_` in it.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE  table_schema='DB_NAME' and TABLE_NAME REGEXP '^[^_]+$';
```